# How set the size of scroll to expand the size of screen?

Tags: css, flutter

I'm trying to make a vertical scroll inside the flutter. I'm using `ListView.builder` to make my scroll based the number of my items. But i have problem and i  don't know how to solve.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
          future: getCategories(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              final categories = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
              return _mainPageBody(categories);
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          }),
    );
  }
  Widget _mainPageBody(categories) {
    return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          _statusOptions(categories),
          Container(
            color: HexColor('#DCDCDC'),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 300,
              child: ListView.builder(

                  itemCount: 5,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return _cardProduct();
                  }),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
  }
```

If i not put a size in the sized box, i will get this error: `Vertical viewport was given unbounded height.` But i have to put the exact size of my screen size in another cell phone it's get diferent. Is there a way to avoid this, and auto expand the size of my SizedBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `Expanded flex`

code snippet

```
Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(child: Text("_statusOptions(categories)"))),
Expanded(
  flex: 4,
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.blue,
    child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: categories.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(categories[index].product),
          );
        }),
  ),
),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class Category {
  String product;
  Category({this.product});
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  Future<List<Category>> getCategories() {
    List<Category> categoryList = [
      Category(product: "A"),
      Category(product: "B"),
      Category(product: "C"),
      Category(product: "D"),
      Category(product: "E"),
      Category(product: "F"),
      Category(product: "G"),
      Category(product: "H"),
      Category(product: "I"),
      Category(product: "J"),
      Category(product: "K"),
      Category(product: "L"),
    ];
    return Future.value(categoryList);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: getCategories(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                //final categories = json.decode(snapshot.data.toString());
                final categories = snapshot.data;
                return _mainPageBody(categories);
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            }),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _mainPageBody(categories) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        //_statusOptions(categories),
        Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(child: Text("_statusOptions(categories)"))),
        Expanded(
          flex: 4,
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: categories.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(categories[index].product),
                  );
                }),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```